# What's the difference between cursor_up (cuu1) and key_up (kcuu1) in terminfo(5)?

Tags: unix, terminal, ncurses, terminfo, tput

In [terminfo(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html):

| Variable String | Capname | TCap Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cursor_up | cuu1 | up | up one line |
| key_up | kcuu1 | ku | up-arrow key |

I tried with `tput` and they produce the same output:

```
$ tput cuu1  | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 41                                      |.[A|
00000003
$ tput kcuu1 | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 41                                      |.[A|
00000003
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a terminfo description, names beginning with **`k`** denote *keys*, while other names are used for non-key capabilities.  For most keys, there is no readily apparent relationship between the keys and an existing escape sequence, but cursor-keys are the exception.

Whether they are the same or not depends upon the terminal description.  For `TERM=linux`, they happen to be the same, however a terminal description could be written for the Linux console where they are **not**.

The distinction is whether the terminal is *initialized* into *application mode* or left in the (default/power-up) *normal mode*.  In application mode, the cursor keys would send <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`O`**</kbd> as a prefix rather than <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd>.

A little over half (54%) of the terminal descriptions in the ncurses [terminal database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database) use *application mode*, meaning that `cuu1` is more often than not different from `kcuu1`.

There's another quirk to be aware of: for other cursor movement, such as `cud1`, the terminal description may say **`\n`**, while the key for cursor-down would not send that character (see [`iTerm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-i_Term_app) for example).

Further reading:

- [My cursor keys do not work](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode)

Comment: Thanks. Just tried `TERM=xterm` and found `cuu1=\E[A`, `kcuu1=\EOA`. And for `TERM=screen`: `cuu1=\EM`, `kcuu1=\EOA`.

Answer (score 1):

`cursor_up` is the control sequence sent by the host to the terminal to move the cursor up a line.

`key_up` is the control sequence sent by the terminal to the host when the up arrow key is pressed.

In VT100-based terminals (which includes all sane modern terminal emulators), these sequences are identical. However, some older terminal hardware may have used different sequences in these two roles, so terminfo keeps them separate.

Comment: In `xterm` (which is not a older hardware terminal), `cursor_up` and `key_up` is different.